# Find a string in a pdf file using python

Tags: python, string, pdf

I want to search through a pdf file and find the page that contains a specific phrase. What I have so far is:

```
object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader("20220625.pdf")
numpages = object.getNumPages()
string = "SYSTEM WIDE OUTLET SUMMARY"
for i in range(0, numpages):
    page = object.getPage(i)
    text = page.extractText()
    if text.find(string):
        print(i)
```

The output of this code is:
0
1
2
3
...

I also used "if string in text" instead of "text.find(string)", but it did not work either.

This is surprising since this phrase only exists on page 77!

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the content of the text variable? or even better, provide the pdf file if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_find.asp) describing the `str.find` method, which you are using in `text.find(string)`. The `find` method returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified value unless it cannot find that value in which case it returns `-1`. So the statement `text.find(string)` returns `-1` when it cannot find the string.

Conditions in an `if` sentence will have the `bool` function applied to evaluate the truthiness. If you try to run `bool(-1)` in a console you will see that it evaluates to `True`.

So the condition in your `if` sentence will always evaluate to `True`, unless `string` is at the beginning of the page, in which case `text.find(string)` evaluates to `0` which is falsy.

**Solution:** Rather than using `str.find` to check for containment of a string, you should use the `in` operator i.e.:

```py
...
if string in text:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I tried your solution, but it does not return any results. Even when I look at the page with the specified string, the code does not work. This is part of the page with the correct string (SYSTEM WIDE OUTLET SUMMARY) in it: private state  regulatory agencies.   TABLE NO. 1 SYSTEM WIDE OUTLET SUMMARY FOR FISCAL YEARS 2019 TO 2021  
Outlet Type  Year Outlets At The Start 
Of The Year Outlets At The End Of 
The Year Net Change*

Comment: @ShazAl, there is no way of telling if the text you posted here corresponds to the string Python gets when calling `text = page.extractText()`. I suggest you debug your script to study what is in the `text` variable. E.g. add the line `print(text)` before the `if`. That should give you an idea about what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition test. The following code is going to work.

```py
t = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader("20220625.pdf")
numpages = t.getNumPages()
string = "SYSTEM WIDE OUTLET SUMMARY"
for i in range(0, numpages):
    page = t.getPage(i)
    text = page.extractText()
    if string in text:  # changed here
        print(i)
```